# The same scale for x-axis and y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I want to make the same scale in both axes x and y, do you have an idea what is wrong in this code?

Here is the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=center,
             axis y line=center,
             xlabel style={below right},
            ylabel style={above left},
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick=\empty,
           ]
                    \addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-2:5}] {x^3-3*x} node[pos=.8, above]{$f$};
          \addplot[name path=G,green,domain={-2:5}] {6*x}node[pos=.1, below]{$g$};
          \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=-1:4}];

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE. As to your question, you might want to type `axis equal` to your `axis` preamble.

Comment: what do you mean by MWE? sorry I didn't get your answer, can you explain more.

Comment: A MWE is a Minimal Working Example - basically your attempt manifested in code **that compiles** (you traditionally comment out the critical portion of the code).

Answer (score 4):

You might want to readjust the soft clip regions and node positions but if you want the axes to be scaled equally you can add `axis equal` key.

```
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween, patterns}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=center,
                 axis y line=center,
                 xlabel style={below right},
                 ylabel style={above left},
                 ytick=\empty,
                 xtick=\empty,
                 axis equal % <---
           ]
          \addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-2:5}] {x^3-3*x} node[pos=.8, above]{$f$};
          \addplot[name path=G,green,domain={-2:5}] {6*x}node[pos=.1, below]{$g$};
          \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=-1:4}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```